# __dopostback slow in ie, no problems in ff or chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I'm working in an asp.net application which uses html 4. We have a link button with __dopostback which should go to out button_click event in the back-end.

In Firefox or Chrome, this works without problems. It goes to the event instantly and doesn't slow our application whatsoever.

IE on the other hand is a pain to work with. Our application becomes extremely slow. Read this as pages takes 20 minutes to load instead of being instant. This continues, until we close IE entirerly or manage to reload the page where we clicked the link with __dopostback.

I want to know if anyone has had this happen before or whether or not there are fixes for this.

We have the following javascript code in the page:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
```

The way I call this function:

```
<a onclick="onclick stuff happens here" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;jobhistory$DelegateCancelLinkButton&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Annuleren</a>
```

Comment: Please post the JavaScript that calls the `__doPostBack` method.

Comment: I have added the way I call the postback. It's the href attribute of the hyperlink.